# shp2pgsql "ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions"

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.6

I'm using the script provided by [`loader_generate_script`](https://postgis.net/docs/Loader_Generate_Script.html) in Postgis to load Tiger census data and I'm getting an error while loading EDGE data. I was able to locate the error by appending `-v ON_ERROR_EXIT=1` to all `psql` calls.

```
NOTICE:  INSERT INTO tiger_data.al_edges(statefp,countyfp,tlid,tfidl,tfidr,mtfcc,fullname,smid,lfromadd,ltoadd,rfromadd,rtoadd,zipl,zipr,featcat,hydroflg,railflg,roadflg,olfflg,passflg,divroad,exttyp,ttyp,deckedroad,artpath,persist,gcseflg,offsetl,offsetr,tnidf,tnidt,the_geom) SELECT statefp,countyfp,tlid,tfidl,tfidr,mtfcc,fullname,smid,lfromadd,ltoadd,rfromadd,rtoadd,zipl,zipr,featcat,hydroflg,railflg,roadflg,olfflg,passflg,exttyp,ttyp,deckedroad,artpath,persist,gcseflg,offsetl,offsetr,tnidf,tnidt,the_geom FROM tiger_staging.al_edges;
ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions
LINE 1: ...tpath,persist,gcseflg,offsetl,offsetr,tnidf,tnidt,the_geom) ...
```

The error says pretty clearly that the columns don't match (the `SELECT` statement is missing a column called `divroad`. How do I mitigate that in `shp2psql` since that is what is creating the `INSERT` statement. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue stems from my postgis version. The Azure managed postgres uses `POSTGIS="2.3.2 r15302"` as the Postgis extension and it looks like TIGER2017 data issues were patched in [`2.4.1` of postgis](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3815). The solution is to upgrade Postgis, though that may mean not using Azure managed for now.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Consider setting the question as solved.